# Is Java still needed to program android games with NDK?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I want to learn how to program Android games, but I do not know any java, only C++. Will I need to learn Java in order to use the NDK?

Comment: If you are going to vote a question down let the guy know why

Comment: @doron - I agree. Anonymous down-voting has its "down" sides. It seems to be happening with these "user*" type accounts though. Who really names their account user1608145?

Comment: Java is very similar to C++ anyway

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at [The Native Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html), you should be able to write a game without using Java. Just be aware that a lot of the Android framework uses java and you may need JNI to get to things.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Cocos2d-X ( http://www.cocos2d-x.org/ ) or a similar library and write 99% of your game in C++, but you will still need a tiny amount of java glue code.